# PostgreSQL Join not working with special Characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table (for example Book) with the column name (character varying) part of it. I imported data from a csv to this table. Unfortunately, in the CSV's name column, almost all the rows contained a few special characters such as `/` and `_`.

Now I have another csv which contains 2 columns which are the invalid name column which was imported and the correct name value as the other column. I imported this into a new table I created, which after update I will delete. When I try to combine the tables to update, the columns with special characters do not show up.

```
select b.name from Book b JOIN tempBook tb on b.name= tb.invalid_name;
```

returns 0 rows though manual checking confirmed both values are same for a few hundred columns.

I cannot delete and re import data to the Book table because it's live data and other columns have been modified. Is there a way for me to query and match the tables where both matching columns contain special characters?

EDIT

Sample data

```
Book
HarryN/APotter

tempBook
HarryN/APotter
```

But the query added previously returns 0 results. I'm expecting the results to be

```
HarryN/APotter
```

Comment: Add some sample table data. And the expected result!

Comment: Added sample data under Edit

Comment: Maybe there is trailing whitespace in one of the fields ? (or both) Try: `... on  TRIM(b.name) = TRIM(tb.invalid_name);`

Comment: I tried TRIM, ilike, still did not work. The column is of type character varying, if that helps.

Comment: If they're the same then this will only show your problem row once, but if they're actually different *(white space, control characters, etc, etc)* then you will see it twice.  `SELECT name FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM Book UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT invalid_name FROM tempBook) combined ORDER BY name`

Comment: If column name contain special characters query must be 'select b.name from Book b JOIN tempBook tb on b.name= tb."invalid_name";'

Comment: Can you put together a script that shows this? Because with the information you provided this works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb6c79/1

Comment: @user99560: It's the column *data* not the column *name* that contains special characters.

Comment: Also `LEN(name)` may help to check whether there is some character we don't see.

Comment: BTW: what is `N/A` ; Is that an editor displaying some undisplayable character (such as &nbsp; )?

Comment: @joop : No it's a value that was accidentally added to the csv and got imported.

Comment: Hexdump (the relevant part of) the .csv file(s)

Comment: Due to the sensitivity of the information, i cannot do that. and according to @a_horse_with_no_name the sample data I provided seems to be working, meaning one of the csv file has some invalid character added to it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have other unusual characters.  I would replace the spaces in the *valid* name and use that for comparison:

```
select b.name
from Book b JOIN
     tempBook tb
     on tb.invalid_name like '%' || replace(b.name, ' ', '%') || '%';
```

This is not going to be very efficient.  But, it can get you started on figuring out where the problems might lie.